Is there a scene in Farscape where Aeryn is hanging on to something to avoid getting sucked out into space?
I thought I remembered seeing an episode of Farscape where I believe the ship winds up decompressing and Aeryn is holding on for dear life so she wouldn't get sucked out into space. Anyone know the episode?

Might be the one where they're in the Budong trying to escape, or maybe you're thinking of Crighton when he's trying to fool that wolf dog into jumping out the airlock?

To prevent your question from being closed as "needs more focus," I removed the second question, which appeared distinct from your initial question. It is best practice to focus your question on a single, well-defined problem. Feel free to ask a new question for the other episode you're looking for.

John, not Aeryn, nearly gets sucked out into space in Durka Returns

Aeryn vents Scorpious and Sikozu into space in Bad Timing. John is in the lock but holding onto the wall.

Moya suffers a hull breach in Vitas Mortis. Although it's John, Chiana and Rygel that are in the vicinity of the breach, we see a reaction shot of Aeryn holding onto the wall to steady herself.


For the record, I can't think of an episode where the same happens to Aeryn

There's the one in Fractures where she and John leave the transport to rescue Rygel from the female Hynerian. They're sort of swinging in space. It's kind of cool.

